# how can i use the delete http request using axios and try catch in server.js in mern stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I'm having trouble with my code for deleting a resource using Axios in my MERN stack application. The code I'm using is as follows:

```
app.delete(`/delete/:id`, async (req, res) => {
  const { _id } = req.params; // use { id } instead of { _id }
  try {
    const response = await axios.delete(`/delete/${_id}`);
    console.log(response.data); // logs the response data
    res.sendStatus(204); // send a success response
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.sendStatus(500); // send an error response
  }
});
```

The issue I'm encountering is that when I try to delete a resource using the DELETE method, the server responds with a 500 error. Upon further investigation, I realized that I should be using id instead of _id when extracting the id parameter from the request parameters. However, even after making this change, I'm still getting a 500 error when trying to delete a resource. I'm not sure what else could be causing this issue, and would appreciate any help in resolving it.

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 21
ETag: W/"15-/6VXivhc2MKdLfIkLcUE47K6aH0"
Date: Wed, 15 Mar 2023 22:52:40 GMT
Connection: close

Internal Server Error
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you calling the same route with `const response = await axios.delete(`/delete/${_id}`); `

Comment: yes i am trying to delete 1 element given the id, in the json file my id is stored as _id

Comment: I am trying to understand: with your `axios.delete` line, are you trying to call your `app.delete` line? Otherwise we may need more context here

Comment: yes i am doing that using async await since its http request but i keep getting an error when i test it in .rest file

Comment: This looks to be impossible. What are you trying to achieve exactly? (1) call `DELETE /delete/:id`. (2) delete x by id in your mongodb database?

Comment: i am trying to delete x by id in my mongodb but its not working

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

The above code will go into a cycle of calling itself.

When your react frontend hits the API /delete/:id then the API again hits itself via `axios.delete(/delete/${_id});`. Axios operation will be on your frontend side to hit your backend API. Instead of `axios.delete(/delete/${_id});` add the code of deleting the record from your MongoDB database

```
db.user.deleteOne( { _id: id } )
```